# Adding Dynamic Row with Date Fields jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, dynamic, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a web application I am developing and it includes a dynamic adding & removing rows which is already implemented. However, I am having difficulties with adding the date to the dynamic rows. In the first static row, the datetimepicker works, but on the dynamic rows it doesn't work as if its not reading it.

Below is my code

```
 <tbody class="body">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="count[]" value="1"><span>1</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control stockDate" id="stockDate" name="date[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control stock" id="stock" name="stock[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" id="price" name="price[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" value="{{ $c->id }}" name="vehicle_id[]"></td>
                </tr>
      </tbody>
```

and here is my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.stockDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});

$('#add-row').click(function() {
        var no = ($('.body tr').length-0)+1;
        var tr = '<tr><td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="count[]" value="'+no+'"><span>'+no+'</span></td>'+
             '<td><input type="text" class="form-control stockDate" id="stockDate" name="date[]"></td>' +
                  '<td><input type="text" class="form-control stock" name="stock[]"/></td>' +
                  '<td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[]"/></td>' +
                  '<td><input type="hidden" value="{{ $c->id }}" name="vehicle_id[]"></td></tr>';
        $('.body').append(tr);
    });


</script>
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

write index in name attributes:

```
<tbody class="body">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control stockDate" id="stockDate" name="date[1]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control stock" id="stock" name="stock[1]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" id="price" name="price[1]"></td>
                </tr>
      </tbody>
```

very simple...

---

js code :

```
$('#add-row').click(function() {
        var no = ($('.body tr').length-0)+1;
        var tr = '<tr><td><span>'+no+'</span></td>'+
             '<td><input type="text" class="form-control stockDate" id="stockDate" name="date['+no+']"></td>' +
                  '<td><input type="text" class="form-control stock" name="stock['+no+']"/></td>' +
                  '<td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price['+no+']"/></td>' +
                  '</tr>';
        $('.body').append(tr);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you call `datepicker()` you do so on already existing items on the DOM. When you insert new rows, they aren't initialized. You have to attach it explicitly before inserting the element or delegate the job to a parent element.

```js
$('.stockDate').datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});

$('#add-row').click(function() {
  var no = ($('tr').length - 0) + 1;
  var tr = '<tr><td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="count[]" value="' + no + '"><span>' + no + '</span></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control stockDate" id="stockDate" name="date[]"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control stock" name="stock[]"/></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[]"/></td>' +
    '<td><input type="hidden" value="145" name="vehicle_id[]"></td></tr>';
    
    // Init the datepicker for the new element
  $('#container').append(tr).find('.stockDate').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<button id="add-row">Add</button>

<table id="container">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="count[]" value="1"><span>1</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control stockDate" id="stockDate" name="date[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control stock" name="stock[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="1234" name="vehicle_id[]"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Delegate version. Might be less performant since it gets executed every time the element gets the focus, will depend on implementation:

```js
$('#container').on('focus', '.stockDate', function() {
  $(this).datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });
});

$('#add-row').click(function() {
  var no = ($('tr').length - 0) + 1;
  var tr = '<tr><td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="count[]" value="' + no + '"><span>' + no + '</span></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control stockDate" id="stockDate" name="date[]"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control stock" name="stock[]"/></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[]"/></td>' +
    '<td><input type="hidden" value="145" name="vehicle_id[]"></td></tr>';

    $('#container').append(tr);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<button id="add-row">Add</button>

<table id="container">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="count[]" value="1"><span>1</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control stockDate" id="stockDate" name="date[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control stock" name="stock[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="1234" name="vehicle_id[]"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: when i try the above function i get the error that datepicker() is not a function. How do I go pass this?

Comment: im still getting issues with the "datepicker" not being a function. is there another way where we can avoid going into function for the dynamic second row.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

Comment: on the same page where the table is, and also the script is on the same page

Comment: im working on local host. i have tried so many things and its yet not working. its just giving me that datepicker is not a function. i have searched everywhere to get it fixed but nothing has been done.

Comment: @edmond as you can see here's working fine... the only thing I can say is try to download the datepicker to a local directory and load it from there... just in case